# Where are the css and javascript files of rails_admin stored?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I find this a bit confusing because if I inspect the html of the page I can see the links like:

But on my project assets folder I dont see any rails_admin related stuff.
They have a page on github on theming and customization but I cant figure much of that information

Comment: Can You Please Elaborate Your Question :)

Comment: The issue is: How can I directly view the erb/css/js files provided on the rails_admin gem. These files are being loaded on the app but I cant seem to find them on my project directory anywhere.
Are gem assets even available for me like that? This might be a silly question but im not quite familiar with all the details on the rails framework

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Rails guides about asset pipeline and how to include assets from ruby gems:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems

Adding Assets to Your Gems
Assets can also come from external sources in the form of gems.

A good example of this is the jquery-rails gem which comes with Rails as the standard JavaScript library gem. **This gem contains an engine class which inherits from Rails::Engine. By doing this, Rails is informed that the directory for this gem may contain assets and the app/assets, lib/assets and vendor/assets directories of this engine are added to the search path of Sprockets.**

Answer (score 1):

You can check the paths of your installed bundles with the following command on the terminal (inside your app directory):

```
bundle show --paths
```

then just look for rails_admin on the list.

Answer (score 0):

That's what baffles a beginner like me too. I believe it's in the server's home/user/gems/ruby-your-version/gems... directory. You can use google chrome debug to locate it better.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read ["How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve the quality of your answers.